# How to copy a file to a remote computer's desktop when the remote computer could be Windows 7 or XP?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I'm trying to create a script that copies a file to the desktop of a remote user.  The two computers would be on the same network in the same domain.

So far I've got a batch script that looks something like:

```
@echo off
set /p user="Username of remote user: "
set /p hostname="Target computer name: "
xcopy [path to local file] "\\%hostname%\c$\Users\%user%\Desktop\"
```

The above script would only work for Windows 7.  Is there a way to make it so that the script would somehow detect to see if the parent folder exists before copying, then if it does to copy?  Or can this be achieved with environment variables?

If I just let the above script run as is and the target computer is using Windows XP, then a new directory tree will be created, which is what I'd like to avoid.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994  would work if I were checking the local system, but I'm trying to see if the remote computer's destination folder exists.  I don't see how this article answers that.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994

Comment: 1. Do not overwrite `username` environment variable, not even temporarily. 2. On `XP`, I guess the `Users` folder is named `Documents and Settings`.

Comment: JosefZ Good catch.   I actually used a different variable in the real script I'm using, and just changed it because I used a term specific to my company.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not think the question is duplicate to _Checking if a folder exsists_. IMHO, the OP asks for _what-if_ "the remote computer could be Windows 7 or XP?" rather.

Comment: @RyanBemrose I would in a heartbeat were it my choice.  I don't get to set the budgets, I just get to support the users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just always use the XP version:

```
xcopy [path to local file] "\\%hostname%\c$\Documents and Settings\%user%\Desktop\"
```

It turns out that MS realized this would happen and put in a hidden junction from `Documents and Settings` to `Users`. You can't CD to it or DIR in it, but you can still use it for anything else you'd use `Users` for.

Comment: Note, however, that this won't work if the system administrator has relocated the desktop folder.  That's not a problem for code used in-house, which is presumably is the OPs scenario, but commercial products would need to be more careful.